# Create scenes from a script in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene

My project consists in creating a hundred (this number is given by the user) of scenes from C# script, from a prefab template. I know how to do it from Editor by using Asset.Database.copyasset for example, but what i want is to create dynamically scenes in Run mode, as the number of scene is variable.

I'm just a beginner in Unity development and all stuff and answers were be welcomed.

Thanks in advance,

Armand.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `SceneManager.CreateScene();` API is what you are looking for [-> Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.CreateScene.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. so when creating a new scene by SceneManager.CreateScene(), this one is working well. But how is it adding in building setting as scene. Because otherwise, the scene is missing in setting or am i wrong ?